# How to copy a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an image. After loading the image, I want to clone it and apply some filters.

The idea is to create a shadow with exactly the same shape as the image.
I already did it (see the image below) but the image widget will load twice (duplicating the request to the image).

I want to load it once, duplicate the result to a canvas or something like this, and apply some filters and transformations.

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cache the image locally to stop it from loading twice.

The package [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) and some others do that for you.

You could configure the front image to show a loading indicator and the shadow version invisible until loaded.